# How END one CDI conversation and completely destroy all variable of CDI Bean?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, weld, conversation-scope

I use JSF2.0 and WELD-CDI and jboss AS7.I use CDI@ConversiationScope  in page-backbean.
To go to the one page, I am using the menu-item., As shown:

```
<rich:menuItem 
     label="redirect  to page1"
     execute="@this"
     action="#{myBean.begin}"/>
```

In the action of this menu, the following method is called to begin conversation  and then redirect to the desired page:

```
@Named(value = "myBean")
@ConversationScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
@Inject
private Conversation conversation;

public String begin() {
    if (!conversation.isTransient()) {
        conversation.end();
    }
    conversation.setTimeout(“1800000”);
    conversation.begin();    
    return "page1";
}
}
```

and **faces-config.xml**:

```
<navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>page1</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/sample/page1.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
</navigation-case>
```

So far everything works great.

But if I apply again by the way, after execute conversation.end(), **still no change variables and All values of variable are maintained**. Why?!

after exexute "conversation.end()" ,**variables-value are not reset**.why variables are not reset?Please help me.

Comment: I believe the way its intended to work is that you end your conversation and start a new one.  Where in your code are you starting a new one?

Comment: I have Several page and to go to any specific page ,i use menuItem.
on action of menu ,"backBean.begin()" invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you end the conversation it becomes *transient*. This means that it's content will be destroyed after the request **ends**. This however means that calling end() does not change the beans as long as you're still in the same request.
Another way to say it is that end()'s effect is delayed; it only works for the next request.
And btw: it is not really that the fields are reset; new beans will be injected and those new beans will of course have initial values for their fields.